# Any attachement to email needs to be saved by recipient in right format

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, zip

I have this problem that I cannot find an answer to. I am sending an email using `smtp` and I manage to send my email with the required attachement using the following code (all sensitive information is read from a `config.json` file):

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'Här kommer veckans zip-fil.'

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

attach_file_name = 'C:/..../downloads/Send_20210201_zipped.zip'
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb') 

payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload) 

payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file_name)
message.attach(payload)

session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)

text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mailet har skickats')
```

Now, the email is sent and recieved. BUT,  it arrives as an unspecified file with the name `ATT0001`. At first, I thought it was trash but I discovered that if I save it as `ATT0001.zip` and open it from where I saved it, it actually is the zip-file I sent. I tested with other types of files and it is the same thing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure the recipient of the files simply needs to save the file without having to know its format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not give up on my own efforts to solve the problem and managed to solve it on my own. I choose to not delete the question and instead to share my own findings. I replaced the `MIMEBase` part of the got I share with something including `MIMEApplication`. I also specified the attachement type in the file I shared with the recipient. Here is the complete code. If anyone sees improvements, please do share your input.

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'The subject of this mail'



message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
attach_file_name = file_to_send
file_name_sent = File_sent
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb') 

body_part = MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain')
message.attach(body_part)
    
with open(attach_file_name,'rb') as file:
        message.attach(MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name=file_name_sent +'.zip'))

text = message.as_string()

session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
session.starttls() 

session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mailet har skickats')
```

where `sender_address, receiver_address, server, port` are all given in a `config.json` file while `file_to_send` and `file_sent` are declared before the mail-part given here while `body_part` is a standard message. This is meant to be automated so they need to change every week.